# Extracting the filename off a URL with QRegExp

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

I have an issue where I have a RegEx, [^/\&\?]+.\w{3,4}(?=([\?&].*$|$)), but I cannot get it to work with the function at [ 1 ] below.

[ 1 ] - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html

This is the code I've tried:

```
QRegExp rx("[^/\\\\&\\?]+\\.\\w{3,4}(?=([\\?&].*$|$))", Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::RegExp);
std::ostringstream list;
int pos = 0;
while ((pos = rx.indexIn(url, pos)) != -1) {
    list << rx.cap(1).toStdString();
    pos += rx.matchedLength();
}

return list;
```

It's supposed to extract the filename off a URL, but just returns nothing instead. I'm not sure what's going wrong. Can someone please offer assistance? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing `\\.`? The original only has a `.`

Comment: Apologies, Jonny! Clearly I'm too tired and should be asleep :<

Comment: Okay, I meant to write in the following below:

[^/\\&\?]+\.\w{3,4}(?=([\?&].*$|$))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt has `QUrl` class for parsing URL etc. And there is [QUrl::fileName](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fileName) method:

```
QUrl url("http://qt-project.org/support/file.html");
// url.adjusted(RemoveFilename) == "http://qt-project.org/support/"
// url.fileName() == "file.html"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution to my problem ^ ^